# Python - How to obtain UserID in Alexa Skill using ask_sdk_core.handler_input

Tags: python, alexa-skills-kit

I'm working on a toy Alexa skill and I'm following the example in the Number Guessing Game ([code here](https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-python-highlowgame)). In the example they

```
from ask_sdk_core.handler_input import HandlerInput

@sb.request_handler(can_handle_func=is_request_type("LaunchRequest"))
def launch_request_handler(handler_input):
    """Handler for Skill Launch.

    Get the persistence attributes, to figure out the game state.
    """
    # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
    attr = handler_input.attributes_manager.persistent_attributes
```

this `attr` object allows me to persist information across the session. In the Alexa Developer console I see this data in the JSON under 'session':'attributes' - I also see 'session':'user':'userId'

How do I access the `userId` data using the handler_input in this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the data in the handler_input can be extracted when you convert it to a 'dict'

```
step1 = handler_input.__dict__
step2 = step1['request_envelope'].__dict__
step3 = step2['session'].__dict__
step4 = step3['user'].__dict__
userid = step4['user_id']
```

It may be possible to do it in fewer steps, but this is what got it working for me.

Answer (score 5):

You can actually get it from 2 places:

```
user_id = handler_input.request_envelope.session.user.user_id
```

or

```
user_id = handler_input.request_envelope.context.system.user.user_id
```

It's not necessary to convert the objects to dictionaries

Answer (score 2):

These answers all work, but I prefer using the following helper function:

```
from ask_sdk_core.utils import ​get_user_id

user_id = get_user_id(handler_input)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for **Alexa Device ID** to get.

```
device_id = handler_input.request_envelope.context.system.device.device_id
```